# How can I extract data from another dataframe for rows with same id?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare dataframe A and B, both with a column "id", and create a new column in dataframe A that writes the value of a column "description" in dataframe B, if the ids for both dataframes match. If the id is not found in dataframe B I would just leave it blank "".

B is a smaller dataframe than A.

Right now I created a boolean column that tells me if the id is found in dataframe B:

```
A["found_in_b"] = A["id_a"].isin(B['id_b'])
```

Pd: I tried an approach of comparing the ids with iteritems and then trying to save the "description" value but it wouldn't save anything.
Another thing I tried is this:

```
A.loc[A.found_in_b > 0, 'description'] = B.description[B['id_b'].values == A["id_a"].values]
```

But it didn't work either. I am stuck at this point and any tip or guidance for extracting the "description" column for rows that have matching ids would help me a lot to finish my first data project.

Comment: Do these dataframe have the same length?

Comment: No. B is smaller.I will edit the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a left join.

```
B_tmp = B[["id_b","description"]]

A = pd.merge(A, B_tmp, left_on="id_a", right_on="id_b", how="left")
```

you will have NaN values when the value in id_a is not in the B data frame

Answer (score 3):

Please give an example to explain your problem. From the problem above, I think left join is what you are looking for. Hope this helps:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'val': ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,3,4,6,8], 'val': ['a','c','d','f','e']})

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='id', how='left')
```